# mvc routing and webforms page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Some background:
I create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 WebApplication.
Then I add a Webforms page: `~/ASPWebforms/Test.aspx`
Then I edit the routing in the Global.asax file like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "Test/", "~/ASPWebforms/Test.aspx");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now I type in my browser `http://localhost:54847/Test` and everything works as expected.

The problem is that all other links look like that: `http://localhost:54847/Test?action=Index&controller=Home`

I also tried to change the order of the routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "Test/", "~/ASPWebforms/Test.aspx");
}
```

but then `http://localhost:54847/Test` won't work anymore.

I'm expecting the link `http://localhost:54874/Test` to go to `~/ASPWebforms/Test.aspx`
And the other links work as usual mvc style `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

Thx for your help!

Comment: What are you expecting the routes to be? http://localhost:54847/Home/Index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the first problem on this page:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1589809/4028028.aspx

An interesting sentence from this page:

> Please read the topic "Understanding the Outbound URL-Matching
>   Algorithm" in Steve book.

Answer (score 1):

I can help with the second doubt.

The reason why it wont work is because the routes order is important.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

whenever it finds a match, no more routes will be tested to that request.